# stringstream operator input failing

Tags: c++, parsing, stringstream

What is wrong with this overloaded operator?

I am trying to parse a `stringstream` to an object which has the members `a`, `b` and `c` as integers.

```
istream& operator>> (istream& in, Feedback& object) {
    cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl;
    in >> object.a;
    in >> object.b;
    in >> object.c;
    cout << object.a << " " << object.b << " " << object.c << endl;
    return in;
}
```

The last `cout` is printing 0 for all members.

I can see that the `stringstream` is properly filled before the input operator in this code...

```
cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << ": " << ss.str().c_str() << endl;
ss >> feedback;
```

this `cout` prints:

```
Feedback parseFeedbackData(unsigned char*, int): 10 2 4
```

The output overloaded operator is working fine. You can find the code below:

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, Feedback& object) {
    cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl;
    out << object.a << " " << object.b << " " << object.c;
    return out;
}
```

Comment: This isn't the problem, but do you really need the extra stuff that `std::endl` does? `'\n'` ends a line.

Answer (score 0):

The output of `ss.str().c_str()` does not necessarily give a clue as to what the other states of the `istringstream` object are.

You should add tests to make sure that the reads are successful.

```
istream& operator>> (istream& in, Feedback& object) {
    cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl;

    if ( !(in >> object.a) )
    {
       cout << "Problem reading a\n";
       return in;
    }

    if ( !(in >> object.b) )
    {
       cout << "Problem reading b\n";
       return in;
    }

    if ( !(in >> object.c) )
    {
       cout << "Problem reading c\n";
       return in;
    }

    cout << object.a << " " << object.b << " " << object.c << endl;
    return in;
}
```

This will help you figure out where the problem lies.

Comment: Thanks. It returns in the first if, as expected.